# Jboss missing log4j jar, when deploying maven app that has dependency?

Tags: maven, jboss, log4j, dependencies

I'm in the process of maven-ising and old ant app that we have. I have added a dependency on log4j-1.2.8 in my pom (as it is required for compilation). However, when I try and deploy on jboss (stuck with version 4.0.2) I get the following:

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to find module file: log4j-1.2.8.jar
at org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer.init(EARDeployer.java:244)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.init(MainDeployer.java:828)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:765)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:738)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:121)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:177)
at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:325)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:483)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:204)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:215)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:194)
```

I'm not sure who setup jboss and I don't have any control over its configuration. I can however see it has the following log4j jars in various locations:

```
/opt/jboss-4.0.2]$ find -L . -name '*log4j*.jar'
    ./client/log4j.jar
    ./server/minimal/lib/log4j.jar
    ./server/all/lib/log4j.jar
    ./server/default/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
    ./lib/log4j-boot.jar
```

Does anyone have any idea what is setup wrong? I know the old ant app used to work on the same jboss server. I have tried using various versions of log4j in my pom (i.e. those found in the jboss directory), and even tried adding a dependency on jboss-logging - but i'm just guessing here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding your `log4j` dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>`, as it is provided by your application server and so is not required in the artifact you deploy.

Comment: Cheers, I actually tried that already and forgot to mention - it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work how? So when your EAR/WAR doesn't contain a log4j JAR, you still get the same error? Is there a reference to the log4j JAR in your application.xml?

Comment: I set the scope to provided, so there shouldn't be jar in ear. It's ejb, not spring and uses annotations so application.xml is very sparse, no log4j mentioned.

Comment: Ah this was the answer, I had tried it already but I must have deployed the wrong artefact as I tried it again to make sure and it worked - cheers for the help.

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted.